# Change specific columns to NA when another column equals 0

Tags: r

I am new to r and I have been struggling to do the following. If one value ("y" in the example below) equals to 0, I want to change certain values ("x1" and "x2") to be NA, but leave others unchanged ("x3"). Example:

```
df <- data.frame(y=c(1,0,1,1,0,0,1,0,1,0), x1=c(NA,3,4,7,NA,8,2,NA,3,7), x2=c(1,NA,4,7,5,6,NA,2,3,1), x3=c(9,5,2,4,7,2,5,8,2,2))
```

I want the output to be:

```
   y x1 x2 x3
1  1 NA  1  9
2  0 NA NA  5
3  1  4  4  2
4  1  7  7  4
5  0 NA NA  7
6  0 NA NA  2
7  1  2 NA  5
8  0 NA NA  8
9  1  3  3  2
10 0 NA NA  2
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To do the replacement in 2nd and 3rd columns, you can use

```
df[df$y == 0, 2:3] <- NA
```

Or, to specify the columns by name

```
df[df$y == 0, c("x1", "x2")] <- NA
```

Alternatively, using `library(data.table)`, we can do

```
setDT(df)[y==0, c('x1','x2') := NA]
```

Answer (score 2):

We can use `mutate_at` from `dplyr`

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%
  mutate_at(vars(c("x1", "x2")), funs(replace(., y == 0, NA)))

#   y x1 x2 x3
#   1 NA  1  9
#2  0 NA NA  5
#3  1  4  4  2
#4  1  7  7  4
#5  0 NA NA  7
#6  0 NA NA  2
#7  1  2 NA  5
#8  0 NA NA  8
#9  1  3  3  2
#10 0 NA NA  2
```